# How to attempt to stop a service only if it's running?

Tags: systemctl

How can I stop a service if and only if the service exists, meaning I wish to only get an error code if the service exists, runs but can't be stopped. I shall not get an error code when the service either does not exist, or when the server is already stopped or successfully stopped.

`systemctl stop foobar.service || true` will swallow any failed attempts to stop a running service, which is too aggressive. The objective is to ensure the service does not run and only error when it can't be stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
systemctl is-active foobar.service && systemctl stop foobar.service
```

That will try to stop the service only if it's currently 'active'.